# Is there Launcher or Chooser to show Settings->Application->Background Tasks?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to open Settings->Application->Background Tasks page in my wp8 app, can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), there is no URI mapping for the background tasks.
Maybe you can add it on the User Voice page: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform.